# Adding space to a string after 3 characters starting from right in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement where at first I need to remove all space from a string, then put a space after 3 characters started from right.

I have removed the spaces but putting space after certain characters is not happening.

IE:

```
AX1098 
AX1 098
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//string-functions.html#function_insert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT INSERT('AX1098', 4, 0, ' ');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_insert

To update all rows:

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE
SET YOURCOL = INSERT(YOURCOL, 4, 0, ' ');
```

Comment: plus 1 for the answer. @Mate, shouldn't it be `0` instead of `1` as the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

If strings have different length then:

```
update t set F = INSERT(F,LENGTH(F)-2,0,' ');
```